# Get URL Hash use in Jquery to change class of ID

Tags: jquery, class, url, hash

First off the URL is being posted from a different page:

```
http://www.xxredxiiixx.com/games/
```

click a link to take to example

```
http://www.xxredxiiixx.com/games/PS4/Knack#42
```

This is showing the LAST trophy (#42) for Knack

I have this code already (jQuery)

```
var hash = location.hash.replace("#","");    
$(hash).removeClass("row").removeClass("row1").addClass("row2");
```

The var gets the #42 correctly but I cant seem to alter the class to highlight the selected trophy. The IDs are just simply numbered accordingly

```
<tr class="row<?php echo ($j++ % 2 == 0 ? '' : '1'); ?>" id="<?php echo $xmb; ?>">
<tr class="row" id="42">
```

Any help would be great.

```
.row2 td{
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.row1 td{
    background-color: #242424;
    border-top: 1px solid #121212;
}
.row td{
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    border-top: 1px solid #121212;
}

var hash = location.hash.replace("#","");
$(hash).removeClass("row").removeClass("row1").addClass("row2");

<tr class="row" id="42">
```

Comment: `$('42')` seems like an invalid selector.

Comment: If you're trying to select the tr with ID of 42 then don't remove the hash - `$("#42")` is what you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the `#` leaving you with the string `42`. Then you try to use `42` as a selector which is wrong. Do not remove the `#` symbol.

```
var hash = location.hash; // "#42"
$(hash).removeClass("row row1").addClass("row2");
```

You might want to look at this question:
[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Perfect Thanks Will marked this as solved (when it allows me)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to give dot `.` in `addClass` and `removeClass` functions.

```
$(hash).removeClass("row row1").addClass("row2");
```

Comment: I have removed the dots and still has no effect. Thanks for fast reply

Comment: Show us the generated html, also tell where you have this jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

`removeClass` is a function only to remove classes from elements. no need to specify it as a `.` class selector

```
$(hash).removeClass("row").removeClass("row1").addClass("row2");
```